# Moment.js: is there a way to return true from isBetween() method?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to find a way to return `true` from a check made with Moment.js `isBetween` method.

In my case: `moment('2020-10-20').isBetween(a, b)`, `a` and `b` are set dynamically. 
In some cases I want the `isBetween` method to return always `true` so I'm setting `a` and `b` to `undefined`, but it isn't working.

Is there a way to return `true` in every case? How should `a` and `b` be set?

edit: here is the use case

`this.props.transactions.filter(transaction => moment(transaction.date).isBetween(this.state.filteredDates.startDate, this.state.filteredDates.endDate)).map((transaction, index, array) ....`

How can i set `this.state.filteredDates.endDate` and `this.state.filteredDates.startDate` in order to make it return `true` if `this.state.filteredDates.endDate` and `this.state.filteredDates.startDate` are not setted

Comment: Can you give more context on how you're using this check? And why you want it to return `true` in every case? Perhaps there's an alternate solution than hacking `isBetween`.

Comment: Of course! I'm filtering an array with `.filter` method. One of its condition is the check between dates so, `isBetween` looked perfect to me. But sometimes a filter over the dates can be empty, this is why i'm trying to make `isBetween` return true with some given values

Comment: You want to return true when either a or b are empty?
Be specific in which cases you want the function to return true and then just write an if that takes those cases into account and return true, else do the moment('2020-10-10').isBetween(a,b)

Comment: I've managed that in a different way, now the check is made on the params and the function is executed only if this.state.filteredDates.endDate and this.state.filteredDates.startDate are setted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want "always true" you don't need to perform any calculations.
So

```
let always_true = true; // or false depending on your needs;
return always_true || moment(x).isBetween(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking but you can use a double bang operator to coerce values into true or false

```
if(!!moment('2020-10-20').isBetween(a, b)){
  //do this
} else {
  //do that
}
```

however if you always want it to return true, why even run the function at all, why not just return true?

```
function(){
  moment('2020-10-20').isBetween(a, b)
  return true
}
```

that being said I'm not entirely sure on why anyone would do that.